# JPA Mapping a Map of Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dictionary

Coming off my way-too-popular question from yesterday:

[Hibernate(JPA) mapping a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266623/hibernatejpa-mapping-a-hashmap)

I'm trying to map a structure that is essentially the following:

```
Map<User, List< POJOWithComposite >>
```

Where `User` is a basic model, similar to the following:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
   public String username;
   public String password;
   ...
}
```

and `POJOWithComposite` is another entity, that has some mapped entities and some primitives, similar to:

```
@Entity
public class POJOWithComposite extends Model {
   public int someIntField;
   public OtherModel compositeEntity;
   ...
}
```

The structure could be analogous to a shopping cart. So the `User` holds the account info, the `OtherModel` could be a purchasable item, and `POJOWithComposite` is a shopping cart that holds items and quantities, say. My analogy breaks down a little when it comes to the main object, but humour me, and let's say for every session we add the shopping cart the user paid for to the list, which will then be archived, say.

Firstly, if the list belongs to each user I could just add it to the `User` model, although I feel that this isn't very modular (i.e. the information isn't really user account information). ATM, this map sits in a utility-like shopping class, which takes care of matching shopping carts with shoppers, to save me from making the `User` model too big. (Is there a better pattern to use here perhaps?)

Assuming that I continue down this road, Let's try and map this `Map`. Ideally, I would like to be able to map it as is. Although I have had very little luck with that.

I happened upon some talk of mapping `ArrayList` easily because it's `Serializable`, although didn't manage to implement that here.

So I made a wrapper entity:

```
@Entity
public class POJOWithCompositeList extends Model {
   @OneToMany
   List<POJOWithComposite> list = new ArrayList<POJOWithComposite>();
}
```

This works. When I use this entity like this, I can map my new:

```
@ManyToMany
Map<User, POJOWithCompositeList>
```

Although I don't really like this solution because I add another mapped entity, i.e. the wrapping entity means another table in the database, which means another join every query etc...

So my two questions are:

1. From the design perspective, is sticking this `Map` in a util class acceptable?
2. Assuming we do map the models like this, how can I improve the mapping?

Comment: To which entity does the Map<User, List<POJOWithComposite>> belong?

Comment: @JB Nizet, its own entity, which should be a singleton-like entity (i.e. only one instance and that instance holds the map). Admittedly not pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a new Entity with `@ManyToMany` mappings on the composite parts, something like:

```
@Entity
public class POJOWithComposites extends Model {

   @ManyToMany
   CompositeType compositePtr;

   @ManyToMany
   CompositeOtherType compositeOtherPtr;

   ...
}
```

That way I indeed left this element of complexity out of my User model, since it wasn't part of the core user entity, and allowed an efficient mapping (foreign keys).

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in creating a singleton entity. You should simply map a one-to-many association between User and POJOWithComposite.

Get a User (using `session.get()`) and call `user.getPOJOWithComposites()` to get all the POJOWithComposites of a given user. If you want them for several users, then find these users with HQL, and iterate through the found users and navigate into the association. The singleton map is the hibernate session. Use its methods to query the database.