# How to map a HashMap with a List as a value in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list, hashmap

As the subject says I want to map a HashMap with a List as a value in Hibernate.
Since it looks like it is not possible to have a collection as element in a map in Hibernate, I have created a class that contains a list of Ids.

My HashMap looks like this:

```
Map<Status, IdList> statusIdsMap = new HashMap<Status, IdList>();
```

Status is either insert/update/remove. IdList contains a List of Ids.

Hibernate mapping looks like this:

```
<id name="id" type="IdType" />
...
<map name="statusIdMap">
   <key column="id" />
   <map-key type="Status" column="StatusCode" />
   <element type="IdList" />
</map>
...
<class name="IdList" select-before-update="true" table="IdList">
    <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="IdGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <set name="Ids" table="IdsForStatus">
        <key column="id"/>
        <element column="updatedId" type="IdType"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

If I try to store the class with statusIdMap, Hibernate generates an Insert SQL that tries to put the IdList class in a column, instead of the Id to the IdList class.
The Hibernate error message says "expected number, got binary".

It's related question to this
[Hibernate(JPA) mapping a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266623/hibernatejpa-mapping-a-hashmap)
where the answer suggests to put list in the Key class, but it's not something I wish to do.

Any other suggestions?

EDIT:
In short the test does following:

Fills object with dummy values, including map.
Initializing hibernate and starts a transaction
Inserts object
Commits transaction and closes hibernate session

The error message comes from the database when trying to commit, since the generated insert statement is wrong as mentioned above.

Comment: please provide code where you tried to insert values in database