# How do I map a Map<EnumType, Double> using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

Let's say I have a domain object with the following field:

```
private Map<StatType, Double> maxValues = new HashMap<StatType, Double>();
```

`StatType` is an Java enum.

How do I map this using JPA?

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853076/jpa-mapstring-string-mapping Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @zeller It complains that Double is an ummapped class.

Comment: Because a map should be a mapping between two columns/tables. Now I think I understand what you really want, but I don't know if it is possible to map single column to a java `Map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another post that maybe helps: [Storing a Map<String,String> using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa). This solves the intra-table column-to-column mapping. If you really want to store a `Map` in a single column, I guess the only possible solution is to store it as a [@Lob](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html). An other SO post that describes this, though, in Hibernate: [How to persist a HashMap with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700150/how-to-persist-a-hashmap-with-hibernate)