# How to persist <String, String> map in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

There's my map:

```
//*many class fields*
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="some_varchar_column")
@Column(name="other_varchar_column")
private Map<String, String> employees;
public Foo() {
        employees = new HashMap<>();
    }
//*getters and setters*
```

Yet, code does not work.

Comment: "code does not work" - could you provide any details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4700372/3899583

Comment: I don't think the JPA specifications allow for this. I tried searching them for how exactly this is done some time ago, but all I found told me this is not a data model supported by the standard.